# Updating SQL database appears to work but no data changed

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, parameters

I am starting out in C# and am making a tool to update a field in a table when the box_id is in the textbox and the button is clicked. I have worked my way through many errors and now everything runs error free, but no data is being changed. Any help with the issue would be a big help.

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string query = @"UPDATE Shipment_SCK
                         SET printed = '1'
                         WHERE box_id IN (@textBox1);";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        Form1 a = new Form1();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@textBox1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = a.textBox1.Text;

        conn.Open();
        int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(rowsaffected.ToString() + " Shipments updated");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to update:" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the "WHERE box_id IN (@textBox1)" is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Oh, I am planning on adding additional textboxes later to be able to update multiple records at once, which is why i did it that way. But, with that in mind... Is there a better way?

Comment: You declare a as a new Form and afterwards use it to take parameter from a.textbox1, unless there is a constructor that informs this value, a.textBox1 will have no value.
If you want to use a form already modified by the user you should use that instance (you can keep a reference) instead of make a new Form1().

Comment: Thanks David, I don't know much about that, I will start researching.

Comment: Need to see the connection string.  Usually when the data isn't getting updated there are two different mdf files.  Most likely the connection string has a LocalDb which is a MDF file that is not attached to a SQL Server.  You are probably looking at a SQL Server that has a 2nd database attached that is not the same as the local db file.

Comment: I have some other functions that read data using the same connection string and they work properly, so I didn't think that would be the issue.

Comment: I think @David is about right with his comment. You are creating a new form right above where you are adding the parameter and unless your form constructor tells the text box to be populated with something it will most likely be blank.

Comment: I have not been able to wrap my head around this. It seems that because Form1 is public and my query is private I was unable to create the reference. I am very new to C# and have not been able to find a great place to learn, anyone have any additional insights to possibly get me over this hump?

Comment: I got it working by changing my textbox to publix with the UI, hopefully soon I will have learned enough to understand how I should have accomplished this. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At this lines:

```
Form1 a = new Form1();

cmd.Parameters.Add("@textBox1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = a.textBox1.Text;
```

You're instantiating a new `Form1` instance, maybe you can't update nothin' due to empty values on your `IN` statement. I don't know your logic and how data comes to the method, but maybe you can do something like this:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string boxIds = "134, 593, 333, 666";

        string query = $@"UPDATE Shipment_SCK
                         SET printed = '1'
                         WHERE box_id IN ({boxIds});";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        conn.Open();
        int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteQuery();
        conn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(rowsaffected.ToString() + " Shipments updated");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to update:" + ex.Message);
}
```

Where `boxIds` its a string containing all the IDs to be used in your query.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,you want to transfer values between forms when you press a

button and the box_id in database will change.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public string text1
        {
            get
            {
                return textBox1.Text;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                    Form2 form = new Form2();
                    form.Show();                
        }
}
```

Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {              
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    string query = @"UPDATE Shipment_SCK
                         SET printed = '1'
                         WHERE box_id IN (@textBox1);";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    Form1 a = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
                    textBox1.Text = a.text1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@textBox1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 7).Value = a.text1;
                    conn.Open();
                    int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();

                    MessageBox.Show(rowsaffected.ToString() + " Shipments updated");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to update:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
   }
```

[image]